# Retrieve version of Nuget package used in console application

Tags: c#, .net-core

I hope everyone is safe and healthy.
I am new to dot net core application and I have a question regarding command line parser.
I am using a NugetCommand line parser package created by a friend in my console application. This Command line parser has a version attribute which displays the version of the system.I want to use this version attribute to display the version of my console application. For example when I type -v or --version it displays the version of the console application. I do not know how I can use the version attribute from the nuget package.
Any leads or suggestions?

---

This is my interface :

```
public interface MyInterface1
{
    
    Version Version { get; }
    int Id get; }
   
    string Name { get; }
}
```

This interface is wrapped in a self-created Nuget package for `CommandLine Parser` called `myspace.commandlineparser.commands`
I have installed this nuget package in my project.

So basically the interface is part of the Nuget package.

Comment: `NugetCommand line parser package created by a friend` can you update post to include the Nuget package you are using? I've worked with a few different ones, but nothing about what you're talking about.

Comment: Users of an app don't usually care about the versions of libraries used by the app, so it's understandable why there wouldn't be a feature for that. You'd probably have to add your own command line argument with code that does reflection to determine the version of the assembly referenced, which still might not be the version of the nuget package.

Comment: Using the CommandLineParser nuget package

Comment: Actually its my mistake in the question. I do not want to retrieve the version of the Nuget package. I want to retrieve the version of the console application using the Nuget Command Line Parser package.

Comment: The definition of version is actually pretty weak and ambiguous. There are multiple things you could ask/look for: assembly version or the assembly file version (assembly level attribute) are the most common. You can't ask for the nuget version: that's not a thing that exists at runtime.

Comment: `For example when I type -v or --version it displays the version of the console application`, it does this by default if you just run: `programname.exe --v` or `programname.exe --version`. Do you want to handle grabbing that from your console app yourself? If so, you can't use `--v` or `--version` because that's a default option already included. You'd have to give it a different short name and long name for you to capture it yourself. Can you please clarify if you just want to capture this version info into a local var etc... based on if user supplies the arg.

Comment: Okay. I have more clarity with my question and problem. I apologize for the confusion. What I basically want is to display the version of a particular class. I have a class which wants to implement an interface. This interface contains a version number , id , name etc etc. When i type the classname. version it should display the version .

Comment: @RohanSharma OK, let me see if I understand you correctly. You want to pass in a classname as an argument to your console application, then return details from that class? The details you want to return would be from this interface the class should implement, correct?

Comment: Yes thats correct.